# Giving write permission to Users group in Vista?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-vista, file-permissions

IS there any API that can give 'Users' write permission to a file in Vista?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to modify the ACL of the file.  For example see related Win32 APIs to: [SetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379579(VS.85).aspx).

If all of that seems a little frightening to you, you can consider simply running a process that calls: `cacls`

For example giving a directory everyone permission:

```
cacls "directoryPathHere" /e /t /g Everyone:f
```

For more information on the command line parameters type in a command prompt:

```
cacls /?
```